# Custom style CSS in MVC Forms

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I make my first steps in ASP.NET MVC 4. I have little problems with style when made forms. Here below you can see what I have in my MVC project. It works fine but dont have any style.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <p>Welcome!</p>
            <legend><h2>Log in</h2></legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RememberMe)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RememberMe)
            </div>    
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

Here below you can see what I separately markup with traditional html. Every element here has there own style cause I used huge css file.

```
<div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1><strong>Welcome!</strong></h1>
            <h2>Log in</h2>
        </header>
        <section class="main">
            <form class="form-3">
                <p class="clearfix">
                    <label for="login">Log in</label>
                    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Username">
                </p>
                <p class="clearfix">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"> 
                </p>
                <p class="clearfix">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
                    <label for="remember">Запомнить</label>
                </p>
                <p class="clearfix">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
                </p>       
            </form>​
        </section>
    </div>
```

**QUESTION:** How correctly to apply the same style (css file) which I used in traditional html to my MVC project?

**EDIT:**

```
<div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1><strong>Welcome</strong></h1>
            <h2>Log In</h2>
        </header>
        <section class="main">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <form class="form-3">
                    <p class="clearfix">
                        <label for="login">Username</label>
                        <!--<input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Username">-->
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { id = "login", placeholder = "Username", type = "text", name = "login" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
                    </p>
                    <p class="clearfix">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <!--<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">-->
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { id = "password", type = "password", name = "password", placeholder = "Password" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                    </p>
                    <p class="clearfix">
                        <!--<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">-->
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RememberMe, new { type = "checkbox", name = "remember", id = "remember" })
                        <label for="remember">Remember</label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="clearfix">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
                    </p>
                </form>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: `new {@class="form-3"}` you can apply like this as parameter of razor syntex.

Answer (score 2):

If you whish to make use of one or more css files you can do the following:

1. Add css to content folder
2. Define a bundle (do this and you get minification and bundling for free. More about that [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification))
3. Add it to your header in _layout.cshtml

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2 (App_Start/BundleConfig.cs):

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("cssPathName").Include(new []
            {
                "~/Content/Css/Base/style.css"
            }
        ));
```

Step 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>

    </title>
    @Styles.Render("cssPathName")
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Don't want to use bundling and minification?**

Ignore step 2 and use this for step 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>

    </title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Css/Base/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Inline class on for example an editorfor**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RememberMe, new{@class="css-class-name"})
```

Comment: Hello Tom! Thanks for your answer. I used the third way which you explained. <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> The problem is that for example I have this element <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> what class I need to use?

Comment: Just do what you do in normal html. Apply the needed class name for example <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" class="class-name-which-exist-in-css-file" />.

Comment: Can you check my post again pls! I updated it with new code which I use right now. Unfortunatly I have empty page and I dont know the reason. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible to know what's causing the white page. In case of an error I would assume you'll get a [yellow screen of death](https://www.google.be/search?q=ysod)

Comment: How are you calling this page? An empty page can mean you don't use this view.

Comment: Well you know, the interesting think is that when I dont use  @using (Html.BeginForm()) and @Html.ValidationSummary(true) I see my form normally. So it seems to me that I dont use them correctly. What can you say about structure of my last code?

Comment: I think you should create a new question for this problem since I think it has nothing to do with your Original question. Please accept my answer if it helps for your css problem. I'll take a look at your other problem if you create a seperate question for it.

Comment: Well, It seems to me you dont understand my question well. Question was not just to add css by link. You say nothing new for me but anyway thanks.    If I will open new question it will be the same. It`s not good by roles of stackoverflow. Last what I add is connected with my question. I just described it in detail.

Comment: What happens if you just remove @html.validationsummary? And what happens if you remove the @ before html.validationsummary?